# Maximum volume of a cone from a sheet of paper

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

We want to draw a circular sector on a $\sqrt{2} : 1$ sheet of paper such that the cone one can form using the circular sector as its lateral surface has maximum volume.

How would this circular sector, drawn on the sheet of paper, look like? Which dimensions would it have and how would it be positioned on the sheet of paper?

So far, I have found out that for any slant height $s$ the base radius $r$ maximizing the volume is given by $r = s\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$, which for the circular sector yields a central angle of about
$293.94^\circ$. However, I do not think that this helps much, since I suspect the cut-out will have different proportions.